# What's the meaning of 乃?

Tags: meaning, kanji

Google Translator gives me no result.

Comment: Wiktionary might be of some help maybe? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B9%83#Japanese

Comment: The meaning and pronunciation of a  Chinese character in Japanese is ambiguous without context. In ancient Chinese it means "is" or "your".　Also I think this particular Chinese character is no longer used anywhere in Japanese but names today.

Comment: Nope.The first few meanings it gives,when written in the Google Translator don't give 乃 as a result. It also says "jinmeiyo" under the kanji, but I doubt this is the sign's only use.

Comment: You may want to try a dictionary. This one ( http://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjif/2697.html ) says 乃 means 「すなわち。そこで。そういう理由で。
すなわち。やっと。ようやく。
すなわち。つまり。
なんじ。あなた。君。おまえ。」

Comment: @Choco: Thanks, but the first few examples have their own kanji too, such as "即ち" for "すなわち". Is this because 乃 is archaic? Also, I have seen it being read as "no". Why?

Comment: These are *meanings*, rather than *readings*...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kanji 乃 was first used to indicate a range of meanings patterned on Chinese usage; afterwards, it was used as a monyougana for the syllable *no*. As such, it later evolved into the cursive shape の, which is now standard. It is sometimes seen on shop signs and the like much like you might encounter "Ye olde shoppe" in England; there, it is usually read *no* and stands for the genitive particle. In this style of writing, 之 is also sometimes used with the same reading. Both usages are considered old fashioned.

Comment: Is it still sometimes used for those Chinese meanings?

Comment: @Qwedfsf [乃至](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162407/meaning/m0u/), [乃公](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/133045/meaning/m0u/)