# How many ways to say father are there in japanese?

Tags: words

So far I knew 父,  お父さん and パパ mean father in japanese. But then I saw other compounds which apparently mean father like 父上, 乃父 (I dont know how these are pronounced by the way). Are there many other ways to say father in japanese?

Comment: Well, searching "father" in jisho.org gives 149 results lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ones used by real ordinary native speakers:

- お父さん (very neutral and safe)
- おとん (informal)
- おやじ (informal)
- パパ (mainly by female/young speakers)
- とうちゃん (informal)

Used only as a third-person honorific pronoun:

- ご尊父 (honorific)

Rare ones used mainly in fiction:

- お父様 (noble)
- ダディー
- 父上 / 父上様 (samurai-sh)

There may be even rarer ones, but this should be enough.

---

乃父 is not a word but a combination of [乃](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32294/5010) and 父【ちち】.